# Node/Mongo: How to insert variable properly so the queries can be efficient?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm inserting inputs (errors or proper insertions) in mongoDB through Node.js. Those inputs are stored in a variable. Here's what I have

```
collection.insert({
                        "fields": 
                            {
                                "fname": [stackErrors]
                                                              
                              },
                        }), (etc)
```

And the output of a find() query is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("592bfb979b047027983a7283"),
"fields" : {
    "fname" : [
        {
            "message" : "expected '' to be NaN",
            "showDiff" : false,
            "actual" : "",
            "expected" : null,
            "name" : "AssertionError"
        }
    ]
```

But I guess I'm doing the insert wrong because I cannot do an efficient query to find e.g. the Assertion errors, which is my goal. I want to find the assertion error or the inputs of the fname field and so on with a proper query. Can anyone help out? Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies, but maybe I haven't been clear. I need to query each form field, I suppose each field must be an object? This is the entire function:

```
function saveToMongo(stackErrors) {

       //CONNECTION

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log("Connected correctly to server");

            insertDocuments(db, function () {
                db.close();
            });

        });

        //INSERT

        var insertDocuments = function (db, callback) {

            var collection = db.collection('http_methods');
            collection.insert({
                "fields": {
                    "fname": [stackErrors],
                    "surname": [stackErrors],
                    
                },

            }),
                function (err, result) {
                    assert.equal(err, null);
                    callback(result);
                };
            
        }

    }

})
```

Like this, all fields are one object. If I want to remove the key "name" and it's value, it removes it from all fields. So, what is the better solution? Do I need something like this?

```
var collection = db.collection('http_methods');
                collection.insert({
                    "fields": {
                        "fname": [stackErrors]
                    },
                    "fields": {
                         "surname": [stackErrors]
                        },
```

Comment: Which queries have you tried so far?

Comment: @makabo this query returns nothing: `db.http_methods.find({"fields.fname":"name"});`

Comment: @makabo well, this one `db.http_methods.find({"fields.fname.name":"AssertionError"}).pretty();` returns the parameters of the query of the fname, but is this the best it can be done?

Comment: This isn't very clear. What do you want to do? What results do you expect when you perform your queries that do work? Show with examples since it will probably be clearer than done with words.

Answer (score 0):

You should install assert package firstly using the below command.

```
npm install assert
```

The code for inserting data goes like this:

```
var assert=require("assert");
var mongo=require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url=//the url for accessing collection goes here.
mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
assert.equal(null,err)
db.collection("<collection-name>").insert({"fields":{"fname":{$push:"stackErrors"}}});
});
```

Comment: well, node is reading `$push` as a key, I dont think this is a solution, and yes, I have assert installed

Answer (score 0):

If only using mongodb refer the code below

```
var db = require('./../db.js');
var ObjectId = db.getObjectID();
module.exports = {
  addUser: function (data, cb) {
   var data = {"fields": {"fname": [stackErrors]}};
    var collection = db.getDb().collection('users');
    collection.insertOne(data, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
        } else {
           cb(err, result);
        }
     });
  });
},
```